# Resolving a Silent Deployed App Crash (WinUI3)

Tags: c#, winui-3

I have a WinUI3 (1.0.1) C# app which builds and runs with no problems under Visual Studio 2022. I can also deploy it (sideload) via MSIX and run it on my development machine with no problem.

However, deploying the signed MSIX to a test Windows 10 or Windows 11 machine -- neither of which have VS installed -- results in a silent crash. The app launches and almost immediately shuts down.

I've run it under WinDbg (preview) and there's an unrecoverable exception encountered:

```
ModLoad: 00007ffa`ba1d0000 00007ffa`ba1f0000   C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\24075JumpForJoySoftware.49446A8871E87_1.0.0.0_x64__4ene0yq67pf8g\System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll
onecoreuap\windows\frameworkudk\dxprivatescommon.cpp(53)\Microsoft.Internal.FrameworkUdk.dll!00007FFAA0E398A5: (caller: 00007FFAA0E7966D) ReturnHr(3) tid(b24) 80004002 No such interface supported
ModLoad: 00007ffa`c5260000 00007ffa`c5289000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\Cabinet.dll
(2f08.17a8): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(2f08.26bc): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(2f08.26bc): Windows Runtime Originate Error - code 40080201 (first chance)
onecore\com\combase\winrt\error\restrictederror.cpp(1016)\combase.dll!00007FFAD924BEE3: (caller: 00007FFAD9255BC9) ReturnHr(1) tid(26bc) 8007007E The specified module could not be found.
onecore\com\combase\winrt\error\restrictederror.cpp(1016)\combase.dll!00007FFAD924BEE3: (caller: 00007FFAD93CCC47) ReturnHr(2) tid(26bc) 8007007E The specified module could not be found.
onecore\com\combase\winrt\error\restrictederror.cpp(1016)\combase.dll!00007FFAD924BEE3: (caller: 00007FFAD93CC6B3) ReturnHr(3) tid(26bc) 8007007E The specified module could not be found.
(2f08.17a8): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(2f08.17a8): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(2f08.17a8): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(2f08.17a8): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(2f08.26bc): Unknown exception - code c000027b (!!! second chance !!!)
KERNELBASE!RaiseFailFastException+0x152:
00007ffa`d798b362 0f1f440000      nop     dword ptr [rax+rax]
```

It's unclear to me how to resolve this, or even to further research what's going wrong.

As an experiment I built, signed and deployed a test WinUI3 app which is nothing more than what VS2022 builds from templates when you create a packaged WinUI3 app. It runs find after being deployed via a signed MSIX file.

The only thing I noticed when I ran the test app under WinDbg (preview) is that it loads combase.dll successfully (i.e., combase.dll doesn't show up in any error message). But I don't know if this means anything.

Advice on next steps (or even a solution :)) would be much appreciated.

Comment: So a "blank" app runs just fine but your custom app doesn't? Then you should implement some kind of logging to determine what happens when it fails.

Comment: Gee, why didn't I think of that? Actually, I did :). The app has a fair bit of logging built into it. Unfortunately, the crash occurs before the code I wrote is executed so no log gets created (and that's even though I tried to implement first chance and unhandled exception handling/logging).

Comment: @MarkOlbert, did you ever find a solution to this? I find myself in an identical position! I am seriously considering regressing to a WPF app - after two months works and only two weeks left of my deadline :-(

Comment: Hi @MarkLazarides! I tried to reply to your comment over on the Microsoft site but their authentication system was bollixed so I'm not sure my response got posted.

Unfortunately, I don't remember the details of how I solved the problem. What I do recall, though, was that the problem was caused by an unhandled exception being thrown very early in the app startup process. And that it involved the way WinApps interact with the file system as regards the location of app config files (WinApps don't store such files in the app directory -- they use a special, protected location instead).

Comment: Hey @MarkOlbert, thanks for taking the time to respond! I've literally just finished moving all my app into a new Solution, piece by piece, running integration tests on production system at each stage. So exhausting. I couldn't find the issue in the end - using a blank packaged app instead of a templated navigation app is the only real difference I can see. Thanks again!